# Extending nested class which is using as property

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, properties, nested-class

I wrote a nested class which is used as a bag for properties. This class is used as property which I named `Properties`.  I want to extend number of properties by interfaces.

I wrote this example:

```
public interface IFirst {
    int asd { get; set; }
}

public interface ISecond {
    int zxc { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass {
    public class PropertyClass : IFirst {
        public int asd {
            get {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }

    public PropertyClass Properties; 
}

public class MyNextClass : MyClass {
    public class PropertyClass : MyClass.PropertyClass, ISecond {
        public int zxc {
            get {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }

    public void test() {
        Properties.zxc = 5; // Here is problem
    }
}
```

But in this case I cant to read/write new property `zxc`.

I think because this still is reading a `Properties` type from parent class - `MyClass.PropertyClass` and not `MyNextClass.PropertyClass`.

I want to extending this without creating new property or hiding existing.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to either ensure that the parent class implements both interfaces, or you'll have to create a new static member in the child class that is of the the nested child type. As you surmise, `Properties` is declared as being of the parent nested type, and declaring a new type in the child class of the same name that derives from the parent nested type doesn't change that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, depending on what you’re trying to achieve approaches may vary. For instance, using abstract class might feet your needs. Like this:

```cs
public interface IFirst
{
    int asd { get; set; }
}

public interface ISecond
{
    int zxc { get; set; }
}

public abstract class MyAbstractClass<T> where T : class
{
    public abstract T Properties {get; set;}
}

public class MyClass : MyAbstractClass<MyClass.PropertyClass>
{
    public class PropertyClass : IFirst
    {
        public int asd
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
    }

    public override MyClass.PropertyClass Properties
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}

public class MyNextClass : MyAbstractClass<MyNextClass.PropertyClass>
{
    public class PropertyClass : MyClass.PropertyClass, ISecond
    {
        public int zxc
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
    }

    public override MyNextClass.PropertyClass Properties
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public void test()
    {
        Properties.zxc = 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but also breaks the inheritance chain from `MyClass` to `MyNextClass`. That being said, without knowing more, that could very well be ok.

Comment: @dlev Yeah, I know it’s not exactly what @nosbor asked… But as you say, without knowing more all we can do is to suggest possible solutions to a possible problem :)

Comment: Bad new... Whan I back to home and tried to use your solution I got error: Error 1 'MyNextClass' does not implement inherited abstract member 'MyAbstractClass<MyNextClass.PropertyClass>.Properties.set'

Comment: Nah, it should work. Give me a sec, I’ll try to find an issue.

Comment: @nosbor Done (fixed the source code). I’ve implemented property in `MyClass` but forgot to do so in `MyNextClass`. It compiles now :)